# What is this caterpillar and how to fight it?

Tags: identification, bugs, caterpillar

This caterpillar is on a sage plant> It's less than 5mm long. It seems to be eating it. What is it exactly and how can I prevent it?

Thanks!

[image: caterpillar on sage]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: I’m in France !